# how do a conditional write in dynamodb with ServiceStack.Aws

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, servicestack, amazon-dynamodb, pocodynamo

In dynamodb, you can do a conditional write (see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html#Expressions.Modifying.ConditionalWrites)).

Now, i'm using ServiceStack.Aws and i want to know how can achieve this (conditional writes)

My code looks like this

```
var awsDb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
var db = new PocoDynamo(awsDb);
db.UpdateItem<Country>(new Country{CountryId = 1, Name = "New Name"});
```

My model looks like this

```
[Alias("TABLE-NAME")]
public class Country
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Culture { get; set; }
    public int State { get; set; }
}
```

But i want to update this item only if have a "state" property in 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just added Typed UpdateExpression support in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/commit/8d48b1325dcaa31006f08e174396e2e2d013b49b) which will let you use an expression builder for constructing an Update query which you can use it like:

```
var q = db.UpdateExpression<Country>(1)
    .Set(() => new Country { Name = "New Name" })
    .Condition(x => x.State == 0);

bool wasUpdated = db.Update(q);
```

Just like PocoDynamo's Query and Scan Expression builders, `UpdateExpression<T>` inherits AWS's `UpdateItemRequest` which you can use to further customize the `UpdateItemRequest` before sending it. Also when a feature is not covered in PocoDynamo you can access AWS's underlying Dynamo DB client with `db.DynamoDb`.

The new `UpdateExpression<T>` builder is available from v4.0.61 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).